# VBA Excel code to search article list

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a Search Box and button that returns all rows that contain what is typed into the box, all cells are string values and there are 350 rows and 6 columns i want to search.

The leftmost column is filled with article names which will become hyperlinks to articles, the next five columns are major keywords from the articles, but I would like the search to look at all rows and columns and then hide or filter the non matching rows.

This approach doesn't seem to be working either, Am I using InStr incorrectly?

Sub Button1_Click()

```
BeginRow = 6
EndRow = 350
BeginCol = 1
EndCol = 8


For ColCnt = BeginCol To EndCol

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow

        If InStr(Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).Value, Cells(2, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ColCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    Next RowCnt


Next ColCnt
```

End Sub

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have been trying a variety of things to get to where I want and I keep coming up with the issue of my search only searching the first column.  I am not by any means advanced in my vba know how and I'm pretty sure I am using a much more convoluted approach than I should be.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. Beginners are welcome, if they ask specific questions showing what they have tried. Your question does not meet these criteria.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't go into as much detail as I should have before, I'm not trying to offend you.  As I said, I have tried quite a few approaches and they don't seem to work like I had hoped.  I am not asking for someone to do the problem for me, just looking for insight on the structure or approach.  Research only goes so far when you don't know what you are looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use excels built in search and filter functions. Assuming excel 2007/2010 Click on your left most column header then in the ribbon under the home tab choose sort & filter => filter. you will then notice a button with an arrow that appears in your column headers. If you click on the button and go to text filters you can choose one from the list. for example "begins with". If you want to hide rows use something like "does not contain".

If you want a more detailed or custom solution Jean-François comment is probably correct. Try something and if you get stuck you can post a question.

To get you started you could try something like this
http://excel.tips.net/T001940_Hiding_Rows_Based_on_a_Cell_Value.html
to hide rows based on a cell value.